# Android Bluetooth Connection changing bluetooth icon? at statusbar

Tags: android

I want to change bluetooth icon at statusbar when connected bluetooth.

But my app doesn't change the icon.

The first picture when I turn on bluetooth.

The second picture is connect bluetooth.

[image: status bar]

Answer (score 1):

I believe that is not possible, those are in the system. Only you can change with root user.

[Answer 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1936742/replacing-the-battery-indicator-android)

[Answer 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9325222/creating-fake-status-bar-information)

Answer (score 1):

You must be rooted to do so.
If you wanna make your own icons copy /system/framework/framework-res.apk to your pc, extract the content and look in the res folder and subfolders for your bluetooth icons.
edit the icon..
then when your ready open the framework-res.apk file with winrar and drag and drop the edited icons in their respected locations, finally copy back to device(may crash at this point) but from recovery set /system/framework/framework-res.apk permissions to 644, clear dalvik cache and reboot